# How to configure resources root for web project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am working with a project with a single "Static Web" module in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 with the PHP plugin (NOT PHPStorm).

Given the following directory structure:

```
-ProjectX
--application
--www
```

I marked the "www" folder as "resources root".  The "ProjectX" folder is the "content root".

HTML references to resources are correctly resolved only in files from within the "www" folder, not when the "application" folder.  Annotated screenshots:

[image]

[image]

This works in PHPStorm, but not IntelliJ IDEA.  How do I get the desired behavior in IntelliJ so references will resolve from all project folders?

Answer (score 5):

After playing with it for a while, I may have a solution.

It appears that ***BOTH*** "ProjectX" and "www" have to be marked in order for this to work.  If you first mark "www" as a resources root, and THEN mark the parent/content-root folder as a resources root, the reference will resolve.

If this was obvious to anyone out there, please explain.  Or is there a more appropriate solution?

SCREENSHOT:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer seems to work in IDEA 2018.2.

Comment: This works in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3

Comment: thanks, been looking for a while. Sometimes IDEA will make you look for it deep. yay